# Polya urn with probability of ball replacement

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, convergence-divergence, polya-urn-model

Suppose we have an urn  that initially contains  $a$  red and  $b$  green balls, where  $a$  and  $b$  are positive integers. At each discrete time, we select a ball from the urn and then return the ball to the urn along with $c$ new balls of the **same color with some probability** $p\geq0.5$ or $c$ new balls of the **opposite color with some probability** $(1-p)$. This seems to be close in spirit to the Bernard Friedman's urn, but it is not the case (as per simulations) that the proportion of red and green balls converge almost surely to $\frac{1}{2}$. How to prove convergence of this process and how to prove the limiting proportion of red balls as a function of the parameters above?

Comment: I suspect you need $p<\frac12$ to get convergence to $\frac12$.  For $p\ge \frac12$, why should you expect convergence of the proportion to a single value?  You certainly do not get it when $p=1$ and $c=1$

Comment: @Henry When $p=1$, this is the standard Polya's urn and it does converge regardless the choice of $c$. Perhaps my question could be slightly more accurate if I had written $\frac{1}{2} \leq p<1$. And I am not sure it converges in this case, although I suspect this process resembles a 0-1 law, and, for that, probably it converges to one (out of 2) possible equilibrium.

Comment: I would describe Polya's urn as converging to a distribution rather than to a single value, and do not see why your $p\ge \frac12$ should be different

Comment: @Henry, you are right, it is a distribution. I am thinking about the expected value of the proportion. Say $X_t$  denotes the color of the ball selected at time  $t$, where $0$ denotes green and $1$ denotes red. Is there a way to show that $X_1, X_2, \dots$  is a sequence of identically distributed variables? If so, what is the expected proportion of red balls as $t \to \infty$?